# Unkown Exceptions in following code

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm writing Windows 10 UWP that takes a picture of a user and then places that picture in another one. (It'll be more useful once I have the specific pictures). Basically, the program seems to be unable to access pictures in my computer no matter where they are stored. The following line:

```
input2 = new FileStream(file2.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

also throws an exception, sometimes saying file2 is in use other times saying that I should place it in a task.run box.

Suggestions? I'm totally new to  C#. Thank you!

```
private async void processing()
    {
        CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
        Size aspectRatio = new Size(1, 1);
        dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;

        StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        StorageFile file2;

        Image playbutton = new Image();
        try
        {
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            playbutton.Source = bmp;
            stream = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }

        Image frame = new Image();
        try
        {
            FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            file2 = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            file2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Downloads\\BingWallpaper-2016-02-07");
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await file2.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            playbutton.Source = bmp;
            frame.Source = bmp;
            stream = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
        FileStream input2;
        var t = Task.Run(() => {
        input2 = new FileStream(file2.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] arrayForImage2;
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input2.Read(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer2, 0, read);
            }
            arrayForImage2 = ms.ToArray();
        }

        byte[] arrayForImage1;
        FileStream input = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            arrayForImage1 = ms.ToArray();
        }


        if (arrayForImage1.Length > arrayForImage2.Length)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < arrayForImage2.Length; x++)
            {
                arrayForImage1[x] = arrayForImage2[x];
            }
            FileStream fSO = new FileStream("C:/Users/Kyle/Pictures/imageCompiled.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fSO.Write(arrayForImage1, 0, arrayForImage1.Length);
        }
        else if (arrayForImage1.Length < arrayForImage2.Length)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < arrayForImage1.Length; x++)
            {
                arrayForImage2[x] = arrayForImage1[x];
            }
            FileStream fSO = new FileStream("C:/Users/Kyle/Pictures/imageCompiled.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fSO.Write(arrayForImage2, 0, arrayForImage2.Length);
        }
        });
        t.Wait();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the complete error and call stack.

Comment: The reason you don't know the exception is because you're discarding it: `catch (Exception ex) { return; }`. Don't do that, you need to know the exception to fix the problem, and `return` does not fix the problem. After you have fixed the problem you won't need the `catch` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> also throws an exception, sometimes saying file2 is in use

I see you are not closing the streams by calling close() or dispose() methods.

```
 FileStream fSO = new FileStream("C:/Users/Kyle/Pictures/imageCompiled.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fSO.Write(arrayForImage2, 0, arrayForImage2.Length);
```

Here, `fSO.close();` should be called after work is done.

Also, `input`, `input2` and other streams that you are using should be checked if they are closed properly.

Comment: Also as @OldProgrammer said, post the complete error and call stack.